# External table does not return the data in its folder

Tags: hive, external, cloudera

I have created an external table in Hive with at this location :

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tb 
(
...
) 
PARTITIONED BY (datehour INT)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe'
LOCATION '/user/cloudera/data';
```

The data is present in the folder but when I query the table, it returns nothing. The table is structured in a way that it fits the data structure.

```
SELECT * FROM tb LIMIT 3;
```

Is there a kind of permission issue with Hive tables: do specific users have permissions to query some tables?
Do you know some solutions or workarounds?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have created your table as **partitioned table** base on column **datehour**, but you are putting your data in **/user/cloudera/data**. Hive will look for data in **/user/cloudera/data/datehour=(some int value)**. Since it is an external table hive will not update the metastore. You need to run some alter statement to update that

So here are the steps for external tables with partition:

1.) In you external location **/user/cloudera/data**, create a directory **datehour=0909201401**

```
                                OR
```

Load data using: LOAD DATA [LOCAL] INPATH '/path/to/data/file' INTO TABLE  partition(datehour=0909201401)

2.) After creating your table run a alter statement:
    ALTER TABLE  ADD PARTITION (datehour=0909201401)

Hope it helps...!!!

Comment: I know it has been a while since this question was asked, but I am getting back to it a bit. There are a few things that I don't get in your answer:1_The table initially created partitioned is no more usable? 2_Do I have to create a new table partitioned as datehour=0909201401? 3_What if I do not have the data to be loaded in the new table?

Thank you in advance and have a nice day.

Comment: 1.) It will be usable only if you create the directory structure the way I mentioned and running a alter table statement. 2.) No you do not have to create a separate table the same table will do the job.
3.) If you don't have data to load then do not create partition.
Will it clarify your doubts ?

Comment: I have done the above steps. And it works.
Am I right saying that the goal was to get rid of the partition?
Thank you.

Comment: Well saying get rid of partition will be wrong. Because in the question you mentioned you need partition. i would still suggest try using partition if it is a requirement. because partition has it own advantages for huge data.

Answer (score 7):

When we create an EXTERNAL TABLE with PARTITION, we have to ALTER the EXTERNAL TABLE with the data location for that given partition. However, it need not be the same path as we specify while creating the EXTERNAL TABLE.

```
hive> ALTER TABLE tb ADD PARTITION (datehour=0909201401)
hive> LOCATION '/user/cloudera/data/somedatafor_datehour'
hive> ;
```

When we specify LOCATION '/user/cloudera/data' (though its optional) while creating an EXTERNAL TABLE we can take some advantage of doing repair operations on that table. So when we want to copy the files through some process like ETL into that directory, we can sync up the partition with the EXTERNAL TABLE instead of writing ALTER TABLE statement to create another new partition.

If we already know the directory structure of the partition that HIVE would create, we can simply place the data file in that location like '/user/cloudera/data/datehour=0909201401/data.txt' and run the statement as shown below:

```
hive> MSCK REPAIR TABLE tb;
```

The above statement will sync up the partition to the hive meta store of the table "tb".