# FAILED: SemanticException org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException while inserting data into Hive partitioned table

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

I have an employee data with 3 departments *A,B,C*.
I am trying to create partioned table on *departments*.
I created the table using below command.

> create external table Parti_Trail (EmployeeID Int,FirstName
>   String,Designation  String,Salary Int) PARTITIONED BY (Department
>   String) row format delimited fields terminated by "," location
>   '/user/sree/HiveTrail';

But this did nt load my table with data in location '/user/sree/HiveTrail'

So I tried to load my table

```
LOAD DATA INPATH '/user/aibladmin/HiveTrail' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE Parti_SCDTrail PARTITION(department);
```

But showing

```
FAILED: SemanticException org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: department not found in table's partition spec: {department=null}
```

1. Why is it so. Am I doing anything wrong?
2. What happens if we `SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict;`
3. While creating partitioned table , do we need to keep data seperated in different folder or whether it automatically get seperated into different partitions

Answer (score 0):

For external tables with partition in Hive you need to run an ALTER statement to update the Metastore for new partitions. Because external tables are not managed by Hive.

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25759568/external-table-does-not-return-the-data-in-its-folder/25760626#25760626)

Hope it helps...!!!

Comment: should we seperate data into seperate file and load them?

Comment: 1.) LOAD DATA INPATH '</path/should/be/data/file/full/path>'...
2.) yes, for each partition you should have data in separate files and while loading you need to mention which partition you are loading the data.

Comment: It will be an extra task right..What happens if we need to load a GB file or something.

Comment: Is this a good approach? First create a non-partioned table and then query the data and load them into partitioned table- https://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2012/12/03/tip-partitioning-data-in-hive/

Comment: No need to create extra table, just follow the steps given the above link. While loading the the data in the partitioned table you need to mention the partition value. Thats it.

Comment: While doing the above link, While updating a value my table get duplicated.Pls see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26902998/values-getting-duplicated-in-hive-table