# Insert overwrite partition in Hive table - Values getting duplicated

Tags: hadoop, hive, external

I created a Hive table with **Non-partition** table and using select query I inserted data into **Partitioned** Hive table.

[Refered site](https://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2012/12/03/tip-partitioning-data-in-hive/)

1. **By following above link my partition table contains duplicate values. Below are the setps**

This is my Sample employee dataset:[link1](http://pastebin.com/tVh16Yxt)

I tried the following queries: [link2](http://pastebin.com/U2yykWpy)

But after updating a value in Hive table,

Updating salary of Steven with EmployeeID 19 to 50000.

> INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE Unm_Parti_Trail PARTITION (Department = 'A')
>   SELECT employeeid,firstname,designation, CASE WHEN employeeid=19 THEN
>   50000 ELSE salary END AS salary FROM Unm_Parti_Trail;

the values are getting duplicated.

```
7       Nirmal  Tech    12000   A
7       Nirmal  Tech    12000   B
```

Nirmal is placed in Department **A** only but it is duplicated to department **B**.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Please suggest.

Comment: It seems like in your first INSERT to the new table all the row are selected.
What does SELECT EmployeeID, FirstName,Designation,Salary FROM Unm_Dup_Parti_Trail WHERE department='A'; return?

Comment: @kabamaru:It return the 9 records without duplicates

Comment: Try to also select the department field on your select and see if this works for you. Eg:

SELECT EmployeeID, FirstName,Designation,Salary, Department FROM Unm_Dup_Parti_Trail WHERE department='A';

Comment: Unm_Dup_Parti_Trail table does not contains any duplicate , duplicates are in partitioned table Unm_Parti_Trail.Unm_Dup_Parti_Trail table is created to load data into a partitioned table.I followed the above link.Dont know if it is the correct way.

Comment: @kabamaru: This is the link I refered https://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2012/12/03/tip-partitioning-data-in-hive/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you forgot the WHERE clause in your last INSERT OVERWRITE:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE Unm_Parti_Trail PARTITION (Department = 'A') 
SELECT employeeid,firstname,designation, CASE WHEN employeeid=19 
THEN 50000 ELSE salary END AS salary FROM Unm_Parti_Trail 
WHERE department = 'A';
```

Comment: Insert Overwrite deletes the entire Dept A and then inserts only the one record we are updating.Insert into is fine. See this post: http://unmeshasreeveni.blogspot.in/2014/11/updating-partition-table-using-insert.html

Comment: @sfotiadis ,, you have missed to select the partition column in your query.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution.

When you do the insert it is necessary to select the partitioning fields as the **last** ones on the query. Eg:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE Unm_Parti_Trail PARTITION(department='A') 
SELECT EmployeeID, FirstName,Designation,Salary, Department 
FROM Unm_Dup_Parti_Trail
WHERE department='A';
```

See this **[link](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/03/introduction-to-hive-partitioning/)** for more info.

Comment: Yes exactly, I'm sorry I thought it wasn't confusing. I've updated the answer.

Comment: But if we do the above query as you suggested it shows "FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10044]: Line 1:18 Cannot insert into target table because column number/types are different ''A'': Table insclause-0 has 4 columns, but query has 5 columns.". we dont need to give department along with our select statement. ANd the link you provided only explains the insert not update statement

Comment: Hmm yes you're write. It probably refers to an earlier version of hive. Which hive version are you using? 

Could you put into another paste bin the contents of your final table after each one of your four inserts?

Comment: Thanks got it worked.Instead of Insert Overwrite we need to do an Insert into and I missed a where class too

Comment: Nice. I've noticed the WHERE clause missing too, see the other solution I had proposed below. If you think it solves the problem you could accept it.

Comment: You can add all these into 1 answer.No need to add as different answers.You can label them as Edit 1,Edit 2...