# Hive: Creating an external table: Show partitions does nothing

Tags: hive

I am creating an external table in my own database :

```
create external table test1 (

event_uid               string,
event_type_id           int,
event_category_id       int,
event_date              string,
log_date                string,
server                  string,
server_type             string,
process_id              int,
device_id               string,
account_id              string,
ip_address              string,
category_id             string,
content_id              string,
entitlement_id          string,
product_id              string,
sku                     string,
title_id                string,
service_id              string,
order_id                bigint,
transaction_id          bigint,
company_code            string,
product_code            string,
key_value_pairs         map<string,string>,
process_run_id          string) 

partitioned by (A string, B string, C string)

location '/data/a1/pnt/lte/formatted/evt'
```

When I try `SHOW PARTITIONS TEST`, I just get OK as an output.
However, there is a table with the same same DDL and the same location in another database which is giving results when I do `SHOW PARITITIONS TEST`. I have also tried `MSCK REPAIR TABLE TEST` which displays partitions .

Please suggest

Comment: For external table you need to add partition separately. Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25759568/external-table-does-not-return-the-data-in-its-folder/25760626#25760626

Comment: Thanks, I have gone through the link but my doubt is: I dont think I have to load the data again since  The location 'data/a1/pnt/lte/formatted/evt' already has the "data" and the files are actually following  the structure  data/a1/pnt/lte/formatted/evt/A=<value>/B=<value>/C=<value>, do I still have to add partitions seperately? then what will happen to the partitions I created at the time of table creation?

Comment: Btw, thanks again. I tried just loading data  and it WORKED. But I still have two doubts 1) as per external table creation script, if we specify LOCATION, we need not to load data again. Why in my case, I am prompted to load data? Is it because of partitions? Please suggest  2) When I followed the second approach in the thread referred by you, I actually need not to alter table to add partition. and even when I tried adding it, I get this error:FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:java.lang.NullPointerException)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using partitions no actual partitions are created when you execute your DDL. The partitions are created when you load data into your table. So you need to load data and then you would be able to see the partitions with the show partitions statement.

Comment: Thanks @Salmonerd.  1)But the Programming Hive guide says that if we specify LOCATION while creating external table & if LOCATION already has datafiles, then we need NOT to load data. So, isn't this in contrary?  2)When I run the query with partitions in the where clause and limit clause, I see the results but the query didnt run as mapreduce job . Can you help me understand this as well?

Comment: I'm confused by what you are asking and it seems like a separate question from your original. Are you saying that you can run a Hive query and see results, but when you write a map reduce job for the same data you don't see any results?

Comment: Okay..Sorry for extending my question. If you see, there are two questions in my previous comment. Please ignore my second question. Would be great if you can help me with my first question.

Comment: When you drop the table even if the data exists in the directories the metadata is lost which is why you can't see the partitions. Running "MSCK REPAIR TABLE table_name;" should repair the metadata which is seems you have already tested based off of your comments.

Comment: I didn't DROP the table. I created a table with LOCATION keyword which has the data files for all partitions  So, loading data again into specific partition, I am not able to understand.

Comment: It's the same scenario. You are creating a new table for a location which already has data for the partitions, but there is no metadata present for the partitions you have designated until you somehow populate it.

Comment: Ok.one last question. If the same DDL in my orignal question but WITHOUT partitions, then I need not to load the data again, am I correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107765/discussion-between-vam-and-salmonerd).

Answer (score 0):

When we create an EXTERNAL TABLE with PARTITION, we have to ALTER the EXTERNAL TABLE with the data location for that given partition. However, it need not be the same path as we specify while creating the EXTERNAL TABLE.

```
hive> ALTER TABLE test1 ADD PARTITION (A=2016, B=07, C=19)
hive> LOCATION '/data/a1/pnt/lte/formatted/evt/somedatafor_20160719'
hive> ;
```

When we specify LOCATION '/data/a1/pnt/lte/formatted/evt' (though its optional) while creating an EXTERNAL TABLE we can take some advantage of doing repair operations on that table. So when we want to copy the files through some process like ETL into that directory, we can sync up the partition with the EXTERNAL TABLE instead of writing ALTER TABLE statement to create another new partition.

If we already know the directory structure of the partition that HIVE would create for next data set(say here for C=20), we can simply place the data file in that location like '/data/a1/pnt/lte/formatted/evt/A=2016/B=07/C=20/data.txt' and run the statement as shown below:

```
hive> MSCK REPAIR TABLE test1;
```

The above statement will sync up the partition to the hive meta store of the table "test1".